# How to install .net Framework in docker?

Tags: .net, docker, devops

I want to install the donet Framework 4.6.1 int the microsoft/dotnet:latest image (this image is needed for .net core, but I need also the framework)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

First, it's recommended to update your tag usage to reference the MCR location (see https://github.com/dotnet/announcements/issues/101) because `microsoft/dotnet:latest` is no longer being updated and still points to .NET Core 2.1 instead of 3.1. So the recommendation is to use `mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:3.1` if you want the latest .NET Core image. See the [Docker Hub page](https://hub.docker.com/_/microsoft-dotnet-core) for all supported tags.

Second, the .NET Core Docker images are only available for Windows Nano Server, which is a subset of Windows Server Core.  .NET Framework requires at least Windows Server Core. So there's not a way to install .NET Framework onto a .NET Core image that uses Nano Server. There is an existing [proposal](https://github.com/dotnet/dotnet-docker/issues/1852) to also publish .NET Core images that are built on Windows Server Core but no such images exist today. [EDIT: Images for .NET 5.0 are [now available on Windows Server Core 2019](https://github.com/dotnet/dotnet-docker/issues/2377)]

What would make more sense is to start with the [.NET Framework Docker image](https://hub.docker.com/_/microsoft-dotnet-framework) which is built on Windows Server Core and then add .NET Core 3.1 to it. Guidance for how to install .NET Core in a Dockerfile can be found at https://github.com/dotnet/dotnet-docker/blob/master/documentation/scenarios/installing-dotnet.md. Do you really need 4.6.1 or is 4.6.2 sufficient? Because there's only a supported Docker image for 4.6.2 but not 4.6.1. The oldest supported version of Windows Server Core is LTSC 2016 which has 4.6.2 installed on it by default.