# Docker .Net Framework 4.6.1 in Windows Server

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, docker

I am planning to use docker for a .net framework 4.6.1 console app, already consider using
.Net core but I have some libraries that do not allow me to migrate to .net core.

I've been researching on docker and .net framework and apparently they are compatible. I would like to know
is it advisable to use docker and .net framework on a production windows server?
I have seen that many people say that docker on windows is not viable in production

Could someone clarify for me if what are the disadvantages of using docker on a windows server?
since I can't understand it

Comment: What has .net framework got to do with it?

Comment: I understand that .net framework forces me to work with windows server.

Comment: Windows server as opposed to what? Linux? Does your .net app run in mono?

Comment: Yes, Linux. I have seen that nobody complains about the operation of docker and linux but it is the opposite with windows (At least the reviews that I have seen)

No, my application does not run in mono.

Comment: I'm a bit confused, really my question is, is there a real problem with using containers in Windows on a production server?

Comment: Can you show us some of these things you've read where people complain about docker on windows?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61716440/how-to-install-net-framework-in-docker
https://forums.docker.com/t/dockerizing-dot-net-4-6-1-app/75594/2

I emphasize that I am new to Docker and maybe I was able to misinterpret the problems.

Comment: And the concern is that this console app of yours only works with exactly 4.6.1 ?

Comment: Yes exactly that is my concern

Comment: Have you tried it with any other .net version?

Answer (score 0):

The Docker Engine and client aren't included with Windows and need to be installed and configured individually. Containers work only on Windows 10 and Windows Server 2016 and later.

The only issue I see is the compatibility version of Windows Server 2016 and up, otherwise it will be listed on Microsoft's website.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/windowscontainers/quick-start/set-up-environment?tabs=Windows-Server