# Docker: Installing .NET Framework in a .NET Core Image

Tags: .net, dockerfile, .net-5

I have a .NET 5 project. I want to use Docker to deploy my .NET 5 project.

In this project, I have to reference a .NET Standard 2.0 project, which references many other projects that, down the line are .NET Framework 4.6.2 projects. It is an overly complicated mess.

Since I wanted to keep this simple, I didn't bring in all of the projects into one solution. Instead I just have my .NET 5 project and then I've made references to the .dll's that are built for the other projects.

One of those projects references System.Data.SqlClient.dll, which I've brought into my project and reference directly.

With my current Dockerfile, I only bring in the .NET 5 sdk and runtime. When my code gets to the point where it needs to load that DLL, I get the error:

> system.data.sqlclient not supported on this platform

Of course it isn't, because I don't have the 4.6.2 Framework installed.

So in my Dockerfile I've added this hoping that it would include it:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/framework/runtime:4.8
```

But it didn't.

Q. How can I install that framework version in my docker image?

BTW: What I'm doing feels very ugly to me... I'm just bloating my image with old stuff... I know that. I can't help it. It is what I'm working with for now.

Thanks.

**UPDATE**

Based on a private comment that pointed me to another post ([How to install .net Framework in docker?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61716440/how-to-install-net-framework-in-docker)), I have tried to start with a window server core image that supposedly has the .NET Framework installed. Then I try to install the .NET 5 runtime and sdk. My dockerfile is below, but:

1. While this builds and runs in vs.net, when my code runs it cannot find System.Data.SqlClient.
2. When I inspect the container or connect to it interactively with a command prompt, "ver" reports it is Windows 10.0.17763.1879. Shouldn't it give me a windows server 2019 verion number? My "base" in my dockerfile is Window Server 2019, isn't it???
3. When I do dotnet --list-runtimes I see NETCore and AspNetCor 5.0.5
4. When I run powershell in the command prompt I see this:

   Get-ChildItem 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\NET Framework Setup\NDP' -Recurse | Get-ItemProperty -Name version -EA 0 | Where { $_.PSChildName -Match '^(?!S)\p{L}'} | Select PSChildName, version

| PSChildName | Version |
| --- | --- |
| Client | 4.7.03190 |
| Full | 4.7.03190 |
| Client | 4.0.0.0 |

Dockerfile:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/windows/servercore:ltsc2019-amd64 AS base
ENV COMPLUS_NGenProtectedProcess_FeatureEnabled=0
RUN curl -fSLo patch.msu http://download.windowsupdate.com/c/msdownload/update/software/secu/2021/01/windows10.0-kb4601060-x64_b645458f512391ae20e17e21f01d24183b5076c9.msu && mkdir patch && expand patch.msu patch -F:* && del /F /Q patch.msu && dism /Online /Quiet /Add-Package /PackagePath:C:\patch\windows10.0-kb4601060-x64.cab && rmdir /S /Q patch && %windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\ngen uninstall "Microsoft.Tpm.Commands, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=Neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35, processorArchitecture=amd64" && %windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\ngen update && %windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\ngen update

ENV ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT Development

#FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:5.0 AS base
RUN powershell -Command $ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'; $ProgressPreference = 'SilentlyContinue'; [System.Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [System.Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls12; Invoke-WebRequest -UseBasicParsing -Uri https://dot.net/v1/dotnet-install.ps1 -OutFile dotnet-install.ps1; ./dotnet-install.ps1 -InstallDir '/Program Files/dotnet' -Channel 5.0 -Runtime aspnetcore; Remove-Item -Force dotnet-install.ps1 && setx /M PATH "%PATH%;C:\Program Files\dotnet"
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 8001

#FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:5.0 AS build
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/windows/servercore:ltsc2019-amd64 AS build
RUN powershell -Command $ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'; $ProgressPreference = 'SilentlyContinue'; [System.Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [System.Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls12;Invoke-WebRequest -UseBasicParsing -Uri https://dot.net/v1/dotnet-install.ps1 -OutFile dotnet-install.ps1; ./dotnet-install.ps1 -InstallDir '/Program Files/dotnet' -Channel 5.0; Remove-Item -Force dotnet-install.ps1 && setx /M PATH "%PATH%;C:\Program Files\dotnet"
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["Ess.Api.Auth.csproj", "."]
#COPY ["../../../../VS19Code/Dev/ESS Lib Auth/AuthBO/AuthBO.csproj", "../../../../VS19Code/Dev/ESS Lib Auth/AuthBO/"]
RUN dotnet restore "Ess.Api.Auth.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/"
RUN dotnet build "Ess.Api.Auth.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "Ess.Api.Auth.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "Ess.Api.Auth.dll"]
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to install .net Framework in docker?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61716440/how-to-install-net-framework-in-docker)

Comment: Thanks Matt. I had seen that and was working through it, but see my UPDATE to my original post.

Comment: @Brent you can't use a .NET Framework library in a .NET Core application, whether .NET Framework is installed or not. You need to install the correct NuGet packages. `System.Data.SqlClient` is available as a .NET Standard package mainly for compatibility reasons as it was replaced by `Microsoft.Data.SqlClient`.

Comment: @Brent are you using `System.Data.SqlClient` directly, or using a library that depends on it? You should upgrade to `Microsoft.Data.SqlClient` and fresh versions of the libraries.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, you are so correct. I've been so focused on learning docker and other things, that I didn't think about that. My .NET 5 project references another project that is .NET Standard 2.0, which references other .NET Standard 2.0 projects and those reference System.Data.Client. I guess I'll need to use docker compose and try to deploy my project and the .NET Standard 2.0 project that mine references. And then I'd need the .NET Framework installed and .NET 5, if all of that will work together. Sorry for my ignorance and thanks much for your response and answer.